# Javascript const variable is changing after multiplying with another variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a shopping cart in JavaScript. When I click on the button, the price of item should increase according to the number of times I have clicked on the button. I've tried the below code but it's not working. The problem is that after clicking few times the multiplication goes like this:
suppose initial price =49
49 x 1
49 x 2
94 x 3
282 x 4    (it should be 49 x 4);
I have modified the code,it works fine in  `console.log()` but gives different result if I assign the variable newPrice to `document.getElementById().innerHTML`

```
let counter=0;
document.getElementById("inc").addEventListener("click",
function(){
  counter++;
  const price =document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML;
  const newPrice = counter * price ;
  const  finalPrice = newPrice;
  document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML=finalPrice;
  
})
<b class="mb-1" >price:$<span id="discount">49.20</span></b> 
<button type="button" class="roundbutton" id="inc">+</button>
```

Comment: You didn't have to parseFloat from the innerHTML?

Comment: I don't really understand why you are using `*=` in the first place. The code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. `document.getElementById("discount")`'s value is changing every click because you are multiplying its value by counter and then assigning the result of that to `document.getElementById("discount")`. The only `const` you have declared is `newPrice` which is defined in the scope of the event handler.

Comment: You are multiplying against the new value you entered, not the original price....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was mentioned in the comments, your code included in the question is performing as expected. You are updating the value of `document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML`. You need to store your price / unit somewhere.

Included is a snippet that demonstrates it.

```js
let counter = 1
const unitPrice = 49.20
document.getElementById("inc").addEventListener("click",function() {
counter++
const price = document.getElementById("discount")
price.innerHTML = (unitPrice * counter).toFixed(2)
})
```

```html
<b class="mb-1" >price:$<span id="discount">49.20</span></b>
<button type="button" class="roundbutton" id="inc">+</button>
```

Comment: oh..okay, thankyou Sir , I was really confused at this part . But Sir, may I ask what is the need for parseInt() for units?Sorry..I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to parseFloat before you do your multiplication.

```js
let counter=0;
document.getElementById("inc").addEventListener("click",function(){
counter++
const priceElement = document.getElementById("discount")
const price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerHTML);
const newPrice = (price * counter).toFixed(2);
console.log(newPrice)
// store your newPrice elsewhere or you cant maintain your 49 * counter
// priceElement.innerHTML = newPrice
})
```

```html
<b class="mb-1" >price:$<span id="discount">49.20</span></b> 
<button type="button" class="roundbutton" id="inc">+</button>
```

Comment: I agree with the in-code comments in the snippet included in your answer, that is the crux of the issue.

Comment: @dirkenstocks I had no clue! Thanks for the lesson. But then I guess that means that to get his desired result, he should store the base price, and on each click just add that value to his innerHTML

Comment: I removed my original comment because I needed to make an important distinction... it should have read: `parseFloat()` doesn't really solve the issue though, in general it's a good recommendation but it's not absolutely necessary. [Type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) **in this case** ensures the value is interpreted as float.

Comment: It works correctly when I put the newPrice in ```console.log(newPrice) ```but gives wrong result in  ```document.getElementById("discount").innerText =newPrice ; ```

Comment: @DevikaHarshan You **must** store `49.20` somewhere other than the innerHTML in order to multiply by it click after click.

Answer (score -2):

I think this
`const newprice = document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML *=counter;`

should be
`const newprice = document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML +=counter;`

note the `+` and not the `*` before the `=counter`. the plus is adding the star is multiplying.

Comment: But I think  if I do +=counter  then , it will only add the counter to my price value. like 49.20 was the initial price after 4 clicks the price would be 53.20 .I need to multiply 49.20 x (no. of clicks) .